# Modular equations in Haskell

Tags: haskell, equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

I want to solve linear and quadratic modular equations in Haskell in one variable. The way I am doing it right now is by putting `x = [1..]` in the equation one by one and finding the remainder (`` expr `rem` p == 0 ``, if the equation is modulo `p` (not necessarily a prime) where `expr` has the variable `x`). I believe this is a very inefficient process. So is there any better way to do it?

Comment: [This might help](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/261900/88047)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I am looking for a general method. Actually in the expression there are other constants as well which are determined using other means so I cannot manually solve it and then use those results.

Comment: is this a numerical method/algrotihm? if yes, you might want to add the respective tag.

Comment: @ErikAllik Actually, I am not necessarily looking for the algorithm. Even if there is a package that does this, I am fine with it. It's just a subroutine in the implementation of Rademacher formula. Thanks for the edits btw!

Comment: To solve `ax+b = c (mod n)` you need `x = (c-b)*a^-1 (mod n)` where `a^-1` is the modular inverse of `a`  mod `n`. This will exist if and only if `a` and `n` are relatively prime, in which case the extended Euclidean algorithm can compute it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solving modular quadratic equations involves combining:

- the [**Tonelli-Shanks algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm)
- the [**Chinese Remainder Theorem**](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/numbertheory/crt.html)
- and the quadratic formula (i.e. completing the square)

For Haskell the [**arithmoi**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3) package has implementations of these algorithms. In particular, see the [**chineseRemainder**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli.html#v:chineseRemainder), [**sqrtModP**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli.html#v:sqrtModP) and [**sqrtModPP**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.3/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli.html#v:sqrtModPP) functions.

Here you can find some worked examples:

http://www.mersennewiki.org/index.php/Modular_Square_Root

Comment: Be very careful with the `arithmoi` package. It has at least one bug in its prime sieve code that causes intermittent segmentation faults. The code is *extremely* hairy and poorly documented, and despite the package having a new maintainer there are no signs that it will improve any time soon.